# Get Configurable Options in MiniCart Magento

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, magento

I need to show configurable option, I have this code

```
           $productOptions = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct()); 
           if($productOptions){
               if(isset($productOptions['options'])){
                    foreach($productOptions['options'] as $_option){
                         $productser = $_option['option_id'].','.$_option['option_value'];                           
                    } 
               }
                $superAttrString ='';
                if(isset($productOptions['info_buyRequest']['super_attribute'])){
                    foreach($productOptions['info_buyRequest']['super_attribute'] as $key => $_superAttr){ 
                        $superAttrString .= '&super_attribute'.'['.$key.']='.$_superAttr;                                             
                    }      
                }
                if($superAttrString):
                    $superAttrString.'&qty=1';
                endif;
           }

            $html .='<span class="label">Configurable Options: # '.$superAttrString.'</span>
```

For now the result of the $superAttrString variable is

**&super_attribute[92]=3&super_attribute[135]=5**
How can i make to show there Labels instead that ID's

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this should work, inside your foreach:

```
foreach($productOptions['info_buyRequest']['super_attribute'] as $key => $_superAttr){ 
    $attr = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($key);
    $label = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($_superAttr);
    $superAttrString .= '&super_attribute'.'['.$attr->getAttributeCode().']=' . $label;                                             
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much that was it, i need to buy you a beer :) Now the result is look: &super_attribute[]=Red&super_attribute[]=Small, I have a small Question can I add there something like that? 
Color=Red Size=Small

Comment: Yes, there was a typo, it should be `getAttributeCode` instead of `getCode`, I've corrected that in the answer.

Comment: Is there any way to remove all texts and remain only Color - Red and Size - Small?

Comment: or make a separate variable, to add in the html zone:

 $html .=                        <dt><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_option['label']) ?></dt>
                        <dd><?php echo $_formatedOptionValue['full_view'] ?></dd>

Comment: You mean doing this? `$superAttrString .= '<dt> ' . $attr->getAttributeCode() .' </dt> <dd> ' . $label . ' </dd>'; `

Comment: Yes thank you so much, you are the master, you save my life. Thank you